# infinite loop onsen ui + jquery

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, frontend, onsen-ui

I'm using ONSEN UI with Jquery, but it is generating infinite loop of errors in console log. The error is a simple loading of an image not found, but the problem is: it is trying to load infinite time like a loop infinite.

If i comment this code, the loop stops, but I need it.

```js
module.controller('PageController', function($scope) {
  ons.ready(function() {
    // Init code here
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

don't initalize like that...try this:

```
(function(){
    ons.bootstrap('MyAppName', ['onsen'])

    .controller('PageController', function($scope) {
        //My Init Code Goes Here
    });
})();
```

Comment: Thanks! But I still have the problem =(( infinite loading error with the same image that appears in console log 5 times per sec